# Reducing the version of libc required

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, libc

I recently compiled a binary on my Ubuntu Server and distributed it. This is the error users are experiencing:

```
Failed (/lib32/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found
```

Any ideas on how to fix it? I used another Linux distro (CentOS 6) before and it worked fine (for me and other users).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the newer library you have two options

1. statically link libstdc++.
2. distributing your version of the library with the binary and using RPATH while linking.

You can statically link with g++ using the `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static` this should pretty much statically link everything but will enlarge your binary.

Another option is using RPATH the `-rpath` linker option can be passed like so :

`-Wl,-rpath,$PATH` replacing $PATH with something like libs or maybe just . for same directory as binary this way the header of the generated ELF (executable) will know where to look for the shared libraries required and you can just redistribute the shared libraries with your binary.

otherwise you could just compile and link with the version supported on your target machines.

Comment: Are there any downsides of statically linking libstdc++?

Comment: @TheBlackTiger yes, size of executable, load speed, memory used, lack of security updates.

Comment: @TheBlackTiger yes you lose all the benefits of shared libraries, for example code for shared libraries can be shared in memory by multiple processes saving system memory and if a newer version exists that is backwards compatible your application will use that one (the benefit here could be bug fix/performance gain)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to build on the oldest system you want to support.